# Python - Slicing error: IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3

Tags: python, slice

I'm trying a code to slice a 3D array to only look for a [0:,i,j] at a time. For example, I have **arr** that prints:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]]
```

And if I want [0:,0,0] it prints [0,9] correctly. If I want [0:,0,1] = [1,10], [0:,0,2] = [2,11], [0:,1,0] = [3,12] etc. All correct when done manually. But I want this to be automated, and when I try the following code:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)

for k in arr:
    for i in k:
        for j in i:
            print(arr[0:,i,j])
```

It gives the error: IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3
Help?

Comment: This is not a Numpy thing; it's a Python fundamentals thing. It also has nothing to do with slicing or indexing. Your misconception has to do with *how for loops work*.

Comment: To amplify @KarlKnechtel's comment, the loop puts the *elements*, not the indices in the variables. Try printing `i` and `j` instead of the slice and it will be clear.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? you rarely need to loop through a numpy array

Comment: Thank you, @MarkMeyer! Now I understand what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `for j in i:` you're actually iterating over the *elements* of the array and not the indices. So `j` will get the values from 0 to 17. Similarly, `i` will have the values of the one-dimensional arrays, one for each row.

> if I want [0:,0,0] it prints [0,9] correctly. If I want [0:,0,1] = [1,10], [0:,0,2] = [2,11], [0:,1,0] = [3,12] etc.

So you just need two levels of iteration and use `range(3)` to go over the valid indices:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print(art[0:,i,j])
```

Note that you don't need the `for k` part, since you're only iterating over two of the three dimensions of the array.

Comment: `print(arr[0:,i,j])` works correctly for OP, and is a perfectly normal construct... when one is working with NumPy. As long as `i` and `j` have the correct values, at least.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, but it's odd to use that inside a block that includes a `for k in ...` where the `k` is not referred to. In other words, it's easy to tell why the code is breaking. But it's hard to tell what the right fix is, since I can't tell what the code was *supposed* to actually do... Agree?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just re-read the question now, I see OP did mention it. Updated the answer.

Comment: @filbranden Thank you! I was in the middle of replying when I decided to reload the page first. Now I understand what was my misconception on how for loops work with arrays.